# Mongoose, Cygwin and MongoDB - not saving

Tags: mongodb, node.js, cygwin, mongoose

I'm completely new to mongo and node.js so I'm still in a playing stage.

I'm running Windows 7 so I have to use Cygwin in order to use node.js. For mongo I copied the binaries to the cygwin/bin/ folder and started mongod - that works so far. I can create databases, tables etc.

Now I want to use Mongoose with node.js. I installed it via npm and it seems to work, but I can't save my records.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
sys  = require('sys'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

// schema definition
var User = new Schema({
    name     : String
});

mongoose.model('User', User);

// creating an user
var UserModel = mongoose.model('User'); 
var u = new UserModel();
u.name = 'John';

// inserting
u.save(function(){
    sys.puts('Saved!');
});
```

I'm never seeing my "Saved!" output and it doesn't save it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Works perfectly here. The only difference is that I'm running MongoDB directly in Windows, not in Cygwin. Get the MongoDB binaries from it's site.

Comment: I'm running MongoDB directly in Windows, but I have the same problem, I can connect to the database through MongoVUE so everything seems ok, but when i try to save an instance with mongoose, the callback is never called! Have you managed to solve this?

Comment: ok, i solved it, i had to write "127.0.0.1" as the mongodb server, it didn't like "localhost" as the server, a strange behaviours of cygwin environment it seems..

Comment: I am also facing the similar issue.. So tried running mongod from windows command prompt instead of cygwin. But it did not solve my problem. Any clue ? What else can go wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

Just ran into this issue. Try adding the following line to your hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
```

Your hosts file should be somewhere around `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`

Comment: Windows 7 uses the IPv6 address ::1 for localhost by default, so specifying an IPv4 address for localhost in the hosts file changes it to IPv4, which is maybe the protocol that mongodb uses.  Note that the etc directory may be hidden and the hosts file editable only when you edit the file as an administrator.